# ionic local notifications decling the dialog box

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, localnotification

according to the local notifications [offical documentations](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#permissions):

> If requesting via plug-in, a system dialog does pop up for the first time. Later its only possible to tweak the settings through the system settings.

So when declining the dialog box you will not be able to show this dialog again? is there a way around this so that you may ask the user again for permissions to send notifications?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't show this dialog twice if denied once.

But you can check if you have permission with `hasPermission` function:
`cordova.plugins.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) { ... });`

If this is falsy you can show a custom dialog, from where you navigate the user to the local `setting/permission` of you app.

Check out this [cordova open native setting](https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-open-native-settings) plugin.

Comment: @Nobert thank you for your answer how do i nagivate the user to the permission settings from angular?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Check out [this cordova plugin.](https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-open-native-settings)